# Excel defined-name range with `end of column` mark

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

Normally we define a range bay the row & column of the begin and end cell, e.g. `A1:A11`

I wonder if there is a way to define the range which has `end-of-column` marker, e.g. `A1:A~` where `~` stands for `end-of-column`

`End-of-column` cell is the cell which has the maximum index of row in the current column - the last cell with `actual` value in the column.

It would be lovely to have this marker in Excel since we can have defined-name range which auto expands whenever the sheet grows.

Comment: This is directly related to the other [thread](http://superuser.com/questions/404254/how-to-merge-two-excel-columns-into-one) you have going. Why not respond there and ask the relevant question?

Comment: @Raystafarian It is related. Indeed I'm looking for way to merge quickly and easily if possible

Comment: See my solution in your [other thread](http://superuser.com/questions/404254/how-to-merge-two-excel-columns-into-one) using INDEX(), ROW() and COUNTA() functions, it is dynamic.