# How to merge to excel column into one from two sheets in third sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

As mentioned in image from the link here [How do I merge two Excel columns into one?](https://superuser.com/questions/404254/how-to-merge-two-excel-columns-into-one) and the solutionis from the same sheet. I am looking for the merging of column A in 'sheet 1' and column A in 'sheet 2' in column A 'sheet 3'. And should be changing dynamically means if I add something in the cell of column A in sheet 1 or 2 should be reflected in sheet 3.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [CONCATENATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) function in your third spreadsheet:

```
 =CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1," ",Sheet2!A1)
```

This will merge them (dynamically) with a space between each cell. (If you don't want the space, remove the `," ",` section from the formula. Just drag this formula down to do so for the rest of the rows (i.e A2, A3, A4, etc.)

Comment: thanks for reply but I want to add one column beneath another column not side by side exactly like the link mentioned over. In that post the solution proposed is for single sheet. I need the solution for different sheets.