# How to merge 2 excel columns into 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I arrange the data from array B4:C7 into a single column in G, using the INDEX function?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge two Excel columns into one?](https://superuser.com/questions/404254/how-do-i-merge-two-excel-columns-into-one)

Comment: There is no formula which returns the size of the selected range. Any Answer will need to assume the range size is four rows. If the number of rows is dynamic, based on the selection, then use VBA. The same comments apply to the column count of the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as though you specify INDEX function you can use index to do the look up

```
INDEX(array, rownum, colnum)
```

Forumla is-

```
=INDEX($A$3:$C$7,MATCH($E2,$A$3:$A$7),MATCH($F2,$A$3:$C$3))

$A$3:$C$7 is the range you want to do the lookup in

MATCH($E2,$A$3:$A$7) gives you the row number
MATCH($F2,$A$3:$C$3) gives you the column number
```

You could also use VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP($E3,$A$3:$C$7,MATCH($F3,$A$3:$C$3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In **G2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$4,MOD(ROWS($2:2)-1,4),ROUNDUP(ROWS($2:2)/4,0)-1,)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Note the **4** in the formula corresponds to the number of rows in the source data table.